# how to set backGround in Uibutton from the gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating button dynamically in iPhone but I want to set the background from the gallery in iPhone. Now I want to know how to get the image form the gallery in iPhone.

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Answer (score 3):

```
-(IBAction)btnSelectPhotoClick:(id)sender{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) { 
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    picker.delegate = self; 
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];       
}   
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Photo Library Does Not Exist"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];    
    [alert release];
}
}
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo { 
// set it in image view
imageview.image = image;

// If it's from camera, save it!
if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera){
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
}

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
  } 

  // Catch when it's canceled
  - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {     
  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
   }
```

Hope this will be helpful for you if you have any query then let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving opportunity of selecting image to user then UIImagePickerController will be useful. for more info use this URL http://blog.hanpo.tw/2012/01/uiimagepickercontroller-and-simple.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get th eimage from gallery like this

```
- (void)choosePhotos{
   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   picker.delegate = self;
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
   [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
   YourImageView.image = image;
   [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

For More info--- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html